# tar broken pipe error

Tags: backup, tar

I'm using tar to backup my entire file system with the following command

```
tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/test
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
tar: test/backup.tar.gz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: does the folder `test` exist? If not, just create it, with `mkdir test`!

Comment: Yes, I'm running in that directory

Comment: Then just run `cd ..` and re-execute the `tar` command! Just as side info...I would rather backup the system with a live os booting from a USB pendrive for example and the running the backup. You can for instance use `rsync` for that among lot of other available tools!

Answer (score 3):

That error probably means that the `test` directory doesn’t exist in the current directory, or that it’s not writable. Perhaps

```
tar -cpvzf /test/backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/test
```

is closer to what you meant.

Comment: Got it to work with that command! Thank you!